# BLE Issue on samsung devices

Tags: android

Android BLE code is not properly working on Samsung devices whereas it works with other android devices .
Some time we are able to get values doing some work around but it is not works as smooth as we required.
I wonder about the Samsung device behavior any one help me to know about what is the main reason behind the same  and what is the permanent solution of the same.

Comment: I'm also facing same issues with Samsung devices like S5, S7, S7 edge etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Bluetooth 4.0, you must update the Samsung mobile phone system to more than 4.3 .
   Android 4.3 (API Level 18) introduces built-in platform support for Bluetooth Low Energy in the central role and provides APIs that apps can use to discover devices, query for services, and read/write characteristics

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html for details.

Comment: It is already updated and working for all other manufacturer except Samsung. I am using Samsung S3 ( 4.3),Samsung Tab4 (4.4.4),Samsung S5.

Comment: Was this ever solved? I'm stuck on this also on a Galaxy S5.